# Docking station that connects to laptop via USB-C: can I connect it to a USB-3.0 port, using an adapter?

Tags: usb, laptop, adapter, docking-station

I have the docking station from my work laptop (a Lenovo) which connects to the laptop via USB-C.

My personal laptop (an older HP) only has USB-3.0 ports.
**I know for sure** it supports similar port replicators (the type that includes HDMI female connector), connectable via standard USB-3; HP used to make them.

**Can I connect the newer Lenovo dock to it, using an** ***USB-A-female - to USB-C-male*** **adapter** ?

Something like this... ?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

The long answer is that the USB-A dock you remember and a DisplayPort over USB-C dock work very differently.

The USB-A dock has a USB graphics solution (think of it as a low-performance 2D-only GPU), made by DisplayLink, built-in. It's only suitable for office work.

The USB-C dock uses USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode to route an actual DisplayPort connection from the laptop's (potentially high-performance) 3D GPU directly (with HDMI conversion, maybe) to a display (or two). It supports the laptop's full 3D performance.

The USB-C dock *might* function as a regular USB hub (with sound and Ethernet or something) with an adapter. This is not guaranteed though.

Comment: I tested it, it was like you said. For the old HP laptop, via USB-3.0, the dock only works as USB hub and audio. For display, windows gives me a warning stating that it won't work. The Ethernet connector simply does not work.

Comment: If the docking station powers the laptop through the USB C, can you break the USB A port of the older laptop (which I suppose won’t be expecting external power)?

Comment: @user2518618 No. Power Delivery only activates after negotiation.